# VS2012 detects change made outside VS and mark files checked out

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vcs-checkout

On my VS2012 I noticed that if i edit a file that is not checked out in a notepad and save it, in TFs it will be marked as checked out and edited. So far we haven't found too much of a problem of it, but potentially people can get careless and make/save changes unintended.

Is there anyway to turn off that feature?

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is now default behavior for [Local Workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx). One way to 'undo' this is to set your workspace to a server workspace once more. But I suggest you first investigate the benefits of local workspaces before deciding to turn it off. People still have to check in files, so there is a gate between changing the file and actually committing them to source control.